# Apex error SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, null

Tags: apex, community, singleemailmessage

On Wednesday 10/4/23 about 2pm EDT, I suddenly started getting runtime errors from salesforce:

> SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, null

only when the logged in user is a community user.  This has been working fine until now.  No code changes have been deployed.

I am sending this email to outside email addresses (not users or contacts)

Here is the relevant code:

```java
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();   
email.setTemplateId(emTemplate.id);
email.setSubject( emailSubjectText );  
email.setWhatId(caseId);
email.setToAddresses( emailDistributionList );
email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId (orgWideEmailAddressId) ;
email.setSenderDisplayName('My Sender Display Name');  
email.setReplyTo(replyToEmailAddress);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
```

I get this error on the sendEmail line:

> SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, null

if the logged in user is a community portal user
(license: Customer Community Login )

I suspected that it may be due to the permissions granted to the community user profile. I tried enabling system permission `Access Activities` but that made no difference.

The only system permissions granted to the community user profile are:

- `Select Files from Salesforce`
- `Send Outbound Messages`
- `Share Files with People in Experience Cloud Sites`

The community user profile has read/edit/create permissions on the Case object, and other changes made by the community user are recorded as activities on the case.
Before 2pm on Weds 10/4 so did the sent email get recorded as an activity on the case.

I am setting the `setWhatId` to the case Id so that the case id will be included in the email header so that I can process replies and link them to the source case.

One solution I tried (and it fixes the first problem) is to add `email.saveAsActivity = false;`

This solves the error message but now my case id is no longer embedded in the email so responses cannot be linked back to the original case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.